# Post Two pages at once

Tags: javascript, php

The following is my example code to post to pages at once.

```
$.post('mail.php',
        'back_ajax.php', 
        {uname:uname, email:email, tel:tel, memo:memo}, 
        function(data) {
            $('#divMenu5').dialog('open');
            $('#divMenu4').dialog('close');
            if (data == '1'){
                $('#divMenu4').dialog('close'); $('#divMsg').dialog('open');
            }
 });
```

Does the above work well?

If not, how can I send the same form data to two pages by post/get method?

Comment: You can't post on two pages with on method. Take a look at the method documentation.

Comment: No it wont work. You can only POST to a single form using the `$.post()`. But you can use 2 seperate post methods, and of course change the success process to cope with 2 seperate replies.

Comment: `else {
   function postajax(url){
       $.post(url, {uname:uname, email:email, tel:tel, memo:memo}, function(data){
   });
   }
   var url=["mail.php","back_ajax.php"];
   for(var i=0;i<=url.length;i++){
    postajax(url[i]);
   }
    $('#divMenu5').dialog('open');
    $('#divMenu4').dialog('close');
    if (data == '1'){
     $('#divMenu4').dialog('close'); $('#divMsg').dialog('open');
   }
  }`

**thanks a lot who answered my question. I've solved it by using your solutions like above. postajax() and array[] .. :)**

Answer (score 0):

The function signature of jQuery's **$.post** (i assume you are using jQuery) looks like this:

**jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )**

(tanken from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

So putting a second post URL as the second parameter of the function won't work.

What you could do as first solution is to include the second php file within the first while setting up it's parameters in the first which data has been posted to. This solution includes modifying PHP files instead of your JavaScript.

One more alternative to keep your way and be more likely would be this:

```
var postTo = ["mail.php","back_ajax.php"];
for (var i = 0; i < postTo.length; i++) {
    $.post(postTo[i], {uname:uname, email:email, tel:tel, memo:memo}, function(da // ........ 
}
```

If you want data to be passed via **$_GET** use **http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/** or **http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/** (with "type" parameter)

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to send data to two pages instead you can combine both the pages when you need the same data.

combine both the pages or use the below code

```
<script>
function postajax(url){
    $.post(url,{uname:uname, email:email, tel:tel, memo:memo},function(data) {
      ..... 
    });
}

postajax("mail.php");
postajax("back_ajax.php");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`else {
            function postajax(url){
                $.post(url, {uname:uname, email:email, tel:tel, memo:memo}, function(data){
            });
            }
            var url=["mail.php","back_ajax.php"];
            for(var i=0;i<=url.length;i++){
                postajax(url[i]);
            }
                $('#divMenu5').dialog('open');
                $('#divMenu4').dialog('close');
                if (data == '1'){
                    $('#divMenu4').dialog('close'); $('#divMsg').dialog('open');
            }
        }`

**thanks a lot who answered my question. I've solved it by using your solutions like above. postajax() and array[] .. :)**